# How did "rational resample" change the type of wave?

Tags: gnuradio

Flow graph in Gnuradio as below:
[image]

Before running this flow, I think "interpolation 1" and "decimation 1" won't change the signal.

And, I can't image how "Rational Resampler" changed `vector -1,-1,1,1` to "sine" wave.

The final output is below:
[image]

How did "Rational Resampler" change the type of wave?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "to change the wave format". you need to clearly define what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean the type of wave ,such as sine,rectangle.

Comment: that makes little sense in presence of a discrete signal; for example: $-1, +1, -1, +1, -1, ..$ is a discrete sine. And a diskrete rectangle wave. And a discrete triangle wave. What is it that you *actually* need! Ask a single, precise question, please.

Comment: Is `-1,-1,1,1...` discrete sine?

Comment: As `-1,-1,1,1` has only 2 values,how could it be resampled to more values then shape the sine?

Comment: it is a sine; clearly! It's the sine of frequency half the sampleing rate. Any resampler will resample it to a sine with a different frequency relative to the sampling rate. It's really not clear what the problem is you need to solve.

Comment: @MarcusMüller,any documents for `Any resampler will resample it to a sine`?

Comment: wikipedia on resampler? It's a resampler. It resamples. That's literally what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector -1,-1,1,1` is in fact an discrete sine wave (appropriately scaled and phase-shifted), with a frequency of 0.25 cycles per sample:

$$ \begin{align}
f(n) &= \sqrt{2} \sin\left(0.25\cdot 2\pi n + {5\pi \over 2} \right) \\
f(0) &= -1 \\
f(1) &= -1 \\
f(2) &= 1 \\
f(3) &= 1
\end{align} $$

It's not a square wave but let's suppose it is. A square wave consists of a fundamental and odd harmonics. So if we took the fourier transform of this square wave, it would have a fundamental at 0.25 cycles/sample, and a harmonic at 0.25*3 = 0.75 cycles/sample.

But 0.75 cycles/sample is greater than the [nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) of 0.5 cycles/sample. This harmonic can't be represented at this sample rate. Therefore by contradiction the source is not a square wave.

In fact, to even begin to represent a square wave, it must have a fundamental frequency strictly less than 0.5 / 3 = 0.16666 cycles / sample, otherwise none of the harmonics can be represented. A square wave without any harmonics is just a sine wave.

As you've seen, viewing discrete waveforms in the time sink can be a little misleading because by default it connects each sample with a straight line. You could consider changing the settings to draw just the points, which can be a little less misleading but also sometimes harder to read.

Comment: How to change the `setting to draw just the points`?

Comment: @kittygirl I don't have GRC in front of me, but IIRC you can right click it and there's "interpolation" or "display" or something in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

A (non-undersampling) resampler usually assumes that the total signal represented by the original samples is baseband bandlimited (perfectly low-pass filtered), and thus contains no frequency spectrum above half the sample rate.  Any spectrum (at or) above half the sample rate usually just creates aliasing noise (unless purposefully undersampling).

A square wave contains lots of higher frequency odd harmonics (a theoretically infinite number for an ideal perfect square wave).  Look at the Fourier transform of a square wave to confirm this.

When all those odd harmonics are removed (or assumed not to exist) by the resampler before resampling the assumed original bandlimited signal, what you have left (depending on the original sample rate) might be only the fundamental frequency sine wave, which has a *higher* amplitude than any original square wave.

You original graph shows a square wave because it used linear interpolation between points, and thus not only did not remove any high frequencies, but likely added them due to a non-bandlimited plotting interpolation, and thus is showing a signal that is not correctly representative of a (commonly) baseband bandlimited signal that was sampled.

Plot with a Sinc interpolation, and you will see a sinewave.

Comment: A resampler doesn't need to _assume_ there's no spectrum above half the sample rate: it's mathematically impossible, no assumption required.

Comment: Also the "tri" graph isn't showing a square wave because something wasn't removed: it's faithfully showing the -1, -1, 1, 1, ... repeating pattern, which is a sine wave. There are no harmonics there.

Comment: I am not referencing the original graph.  I am referencing the (often) incorrect assumption that this is the graph of a (improperly sampled) square wave.

Comment: @PhilFrost - Wrong.  Without the specification that those samples were of a bandlimited signal, very little is known about the pattern -1 -1 1 1.  An infinite number of non-bandlimited waveforms could produce those samples.

Comment: Sure, any number of frequencies above the nyquist frequency could alias to a frequency below the nyquist frequency when sampled. But your first paragraph suggests there is some kind of other resampler could make some different assumption that arrives at a different result. That's not possible. The resampler is doing the only thing it can do with the information it has.

Comment: your pargraph says "You original graph shows a square wave", but in the comment you're saying you're not referencing the original graph? I am now very confused.

Comment: In any case, your final paragraph suggests there are harmonics that weren't removed, but my point is there never were any harmonics to be removed. The source (a repeating -1, -1, 1, 1) [has no harmonics](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discrete+fourier+transform+of+%28-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%29) to be removed!

Comment: It is possible to resample an undersampled but bandlimited signal of spectrum well above half the sample rate, as long as the original band is known.  Thus a baseband bandlimited spec is usually either required, or assumed (perhaps mistakenly).  Whether there are harmonics or not to be removed is thus based on a spec, or unstated assumptions.

Comment: You're making a Russel's teapot argument. Sure, maybe there existed at some point some waveform which consisted only of the one frequency in -1, -1, 1, 1 or image frequencies thereof, but there is _no way_ to interpret that sequence of samples to show that those harmonics existed. Any information of their existence has been lost, _irrevocably_. You're talking about _divination_, not _assumption_. And in this example, we can plainly see the source is not an undersampled signal. It is literally the sequence -1, -1, 1, 1, repeating, no more and no less. It's right there, at the left of the graph.

Comment: That is correct, information about whether the original spectrum represented by the samples contained either just a fundamental sinewave, or signals of a much higher frequency does not exist without further specification.  Depending on the assumptions, there a multiple solutions to a resampling.

Comment: @PhilFrost : It may be helpful for you to look up how undersampling SDR ADCs and DACs work.

Comment: Good for you. Unfortunately implicitly questioning my qualifications does not change the fact that there are no harmonics in the discrete Fourier transform of -1, -1, 1, 1. I guess your point is maybe harmonics existed in some signal not show or even implied, but all information about them removed by some unseen process that quite clearly isn't in the question at all. That's true, I guess? I don't see how this is useful or relevant.

Comment: A DFT represents an infinite number of harmonics, that's why the possibility of aliasing and undersampling exists.

Comment: It only represents infinite harmonics if you are trying to infer the existence of some analog signal that has been sampled. A discrete function is a perfectly valid thing to interpret unambiguously in its own right, and since the question doesn't ask about or imply the existence of anything else, I really don't see how the point you are making is relevant. If this is really the hill you want to die on, you should also make the point that the middle waveform labeled "sine ?" is _exactly as much_ maybe not a sine as the one labeled "tri".

Comment: It's not possible to resample (except for pure integer decimation) without inferring something about the waveform between the original sample points, in order to create new sample points for the resampled result.  Any inference depends on some important (often falsely assumed) assumptions.  Some plot programs infer linear interpolation.  Good resamplers more often assume something closer to a Sinc, or windowed Sinc (or similar remez-exchange optimized filter) interpolation.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are getting at. Here's a constructive suggestion: perhaps you can point out that concepts like "square wave" and "sine wave" are _continuous_ functions, but we have a discrete one. When we resample, we must first come up with some continuous function the discrete function represents so we can fill in the missing points, and there's more than one choice there. But I think it's also important to point out the choice _nearly every person and DSP library will make_ is that -1, -1, 1, 1 is a sine wave.

Comment: Many low quality (noisy) resamplers also assume linear interpolation.

Comment: Arguing this is "often falsely assumed" is just arguing that the convention that's correct 99% of the time is just confusing and _not useful_ for someone who is obviously new to DSP.

Comment: No, I think those resamplers can only be deemed "low quality" or "noisy" if we assume it's a sine wave, because then what makes them "low quality" or "noisy" is their low fidelity.

Comment: Someone new to amateur radio DSP needs to understand aliasing, as that is a major source of errors (spurious transmitter splatter, receive images, etc.) in DSP software and hardware.  And with poor quality resamplers (a plot graphics linear interpolator makes a terrible audio resampler).